# How do you replace the cupholders in a late 90's (1999) model Toyota Corolla?

Tags: toyota, corolla, interior, plastic

The cupholder mechanism in my 1999 Toyota Corolla broke on the bottom and on the sidebar and they need to be replaced.

How would I go about doing that? I assume the center console has to be taken apart?

Comment: Could you post a pic of exactly what is broke and needs replaced? I could probably took it up and find answers for you, but it would be a lot shorter search if I knew exactly what you are trying to replace.